# How to get the analyzed text from the elasticsearch database

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to get the analyzed text from the elasticseatch database. I know that I can apply an analyzer to any text using the analyze API, however, since the text has already be analyzed during indexing, there should be a way to get access to the analyzed data.

Here is what I want to do using the analyze API and Python Elasticsearch

```
res = es.indices.analyze(index=app.config['ES_ARXIV_PAPER_INDEX'],
                         body={"char_filter": ["html_strip"],
                               "tokenizer" : "standard",
                                "filter" : ["lowercase", "stop", "snowball"],
                                "text" : text})
tokens = []
for token in res['tokens']:
    tokens.append(token['token'])
print("tokens = ", tokens)
```

I noticed that this procedure is actually quite slow. So getting the data directly from the indexed data should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Using the termvectors api should do the job, but you must specify the id of every entry and it must be enabled (since the information is stored). If you don't want that, then you are already using the correct method.

Example below:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "my_field": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST my_index/my_type/1
{
  "my_field": "this is a test"
}

GET /my_index/my_type/1/_termvectors?fields=*
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-vector.html

Comment: hi alkis thanks for the reply... I saw that there is a mtermsvectors API, so I don't have to retrieve each id separately. Do you know whether it is possible to use the bulk API together with analyze API?

Comment: Hi @carl, unfortunately no I don't